# Why processes run from a shell script has parent id 1

Tags: linux

running the following command would spawn a python process with parent pid 1

```
echo "python3 -m http.server 2>&1 &" > a && chmod 777 a && ./a && ps -ef | grep "python3 -m http.server"
```

result

```
  501  4622     1   0  4:45PM ttys000    0:00.00 python3 -m http.server
```

while running the following

```
python3 -m http.server 2>&1 &
ps -ef | grep "python3 -m http.server"
```

will have something different

```
501  4646   665   0  4:51PM ttys000    0:00.07 python3 -m http.server
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All processes must have a parent. If a parent spawns a child, then the parent exits, the child must still have parent. When this happens, its parent is set to the init process, which has an pid of 1.

As for why, the above 2 cases are different... The second has its parent set to the shell pid, and the shell has not yet exited.

As for the first, you are spawning it from a shell, the server is put into the background by the use of '&', the shell then exits. We then go through paragraph 1.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! May I ask a follow-up question on that? Say in the second case, I am using an ssh session, when my session goes time out/die, will the python process die also or be put under parent 1? My current experience is the python process dies also.

Comment: Processes dying like that is expected default behaviour. Once you exit the controlling terminal, all processes linked to it are shut down. Look at nohup which stops this.